# PHP Header relocating and $_GET

Tags: php, header, get

I have a website that allows users to upload a picture, but I don't want any nudity in the photos. I found a scan written in php that I have succesfully implemented. The file and record are deleted if nudity is found to be in the file. I am just having trouble alerting the user as to why there pic wasn't kept. It just reloads the page. What could be the problem?

This code is the beginning of non commented code in my new2.php file:

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) { 
echo "Nudity found. Please try again with a more appropriate picture.";
sleep(5);
header("Location: new2.php");
}
```

This code is the code that scans the pic for nudity:

```
if($quant->isPorn()) {
        $q = "delete from $table where id='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($q);
        unlink("pics/".$picfile);
        header('Location: new2.php?error=1');
    } else {
    header("Location: index.php?id=$id");
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `echo` output won't be seen by the user. Output hasn't been sent to the browser yet, that happens at the end of your script. You redirect before that happens.

If you want to send a message, wait 5 seconds, and then redirect, do it client side.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
    <p>Nudity found. Please try again with a more appropriate picture.</p>
    <script>
        setTimeout("self.location='new2.php'",5000);
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @AlexBridges It should be displayed based on your `$_GET['error']`. I updated my answer with one option.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is not needed. Just output the page containing your error, but change

```
sleep(5);
header("Location: new2.php");
```

to

```
header("Refresh: 5; url=new2.php");
```

This has the same effect as a `<meta http-equiv="refresh">`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it from header. Use this instead:

```
<script> location="whatever.php?a=1"; </script>
```